# Updating Android app on Google Play - Android Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to update my Android App to the latest version.
On Google Play Android Developer Console - Advanced Mode -
I've uploaded the new APK, deactivated the older version, activated the updated version and clicked on SAVE.

I don't see any message after clicking on SAVE.

When I go back to console I still see that older version is active?

I tried the same in Simple mode but same result.

Is there any problem with SAVE - Wouldn't it show some message - something like "saved successfully" ?

Or do I've to wait (30 minutes to a day or so) to see the changes?

I've been searching here and on Google but couldn't find any clarification.

Comment: yeap definetelly a little green tooltip saying "saved ok"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicking save, the button should change to "saving..." for about 5 to 20 seconds:

[image]

After that, in the center of the screen, at the top, you should see a message that says that the changes were saved succesfully:

[image]

I'm sorry the text in the pictures is in Dutch, but you get the idea.

Before the update is visible in the Play Store for users, it could take about 12 hours.
If this still does not work, please try to use another browser to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I did try once in Firefiox didn't work. I just tried in IE and it worked. Thanks for waking me up ;) I should have tried it IE before posting here. It didn't work in Chrome and I thought if it doesn't work in chrome it should not suppose to work in other browser after all Chrome is in Google's eco system.

Comment: I agree. These screenshots were actually taken in Chrome and it works for me... Weird :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Chrome and found it was because I had ABP (Ad Block Plus) enabled. I guess it was preventing the pop-up underlying the button from working. I disabled ABP 'on this site' and all was well after a refresh.